# Two ways of explaining the notation $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory, notation

I found two ways to explain the notation $\mathbb{R}^2$.

First is by Cartesian product: $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$.

Secondly, regarding $2$ as any set with two elements. suppose it's $\{0,1\}$.
Then the map from $\{0,1\}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ forms a linear space. which can be also denoted as $\mathbb{R}^{\{0,1\}} = \mathbb{R}^2$.

In mathematics, if two things looks similar or the same, there will always be some deep reason behind it. So what's the deep reason of the above statements?

Comment: They're two different ways of looking at the same thing.

Comment: We write $\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$ as $\mathbb{R}^2$ just to match the short-hand notation of exponents elsewhere, e.g., $5\times 5=5^2$. The fact that we can also write $2$ as a set $\{0,1\}$ seems independent to me. We certainly *could* say $25=5^{\{0,1\}}$, but what meaning/value are you looking for when doing this?

Comment: $2 = \{0,1\}$ - see [Von Neumann's construction of natural number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number#Von_Neumann_ordinals).

Comment: There is an obvious bijection between elements of the cartesian product which are pairs of real numbers $(a,b)$, and functions $f : \{0,1\} \to \mathbb R$ which are uniquely defined by the two real numbers $\left(f(0), f(1)\right)$. That could probably be extended to some sort of morphism, depending on what structure you want to take into consideration.

Answer (score 3):

The "deep" reason is that $\mathbf{R}^n$ can be defined up to a natural isomorphism by the universal property of products. I start with the most general and abstract definition of a product of sets and then I show how that relates to your question:

> Consider a set $I$, a set of sets $X$, a function $\phi\colon I\to X$ and $X_i:=\phi(i)$.
> A product of $\phi$ consists of a set $P$ and, for each $i\in I$, a function
> $\pi_i\colon P\to X_i$ such that the following holds: Let $A$ be some set and $f_i\colon
>  A\to X_i$ a function for each $i\in I$, then there is exactly
> one function $f\colon A\to P$ with $f_i=\pi_i\circ f$ for all
> $i\in I$.

In the beginning, I claimed that products are defined up to a natural isomorphism - here is the precise statement:

> Let $P$ and $P'$ be products of $\phi$ then there exists exactly one function $f\colon P'\to P$ such that $\pi'{}_i=\pi_i\circ f$ for all $i\in I$ by the universal property of products. For the same reason, there exists exactly one function $g\colon P\to P'$ such that $\pi_i=\pi'{}_i\circ g$ for all $i\in I$. You can show that $f$ and $g$ are inverse to each other, that is $f\circ g=\mathrm{id}_P$ and $g\circ f=\mathrm{id}_{P'}$.

In your case, $I=\{1,\ldots,n\}$, $\phi(i)=\mathbf{R}$ for all $i\in I$ and as you already noticed, there are many different ways to construct a product:

- One way is to define $\mathbf{R}^n$ inductively: $\mathbf{R}^1:=\mathbf{R}$ and $$\mathbf{R}^{n+1}:=\mathbf{R}^n\times\mathbf{R}:=\Big\{\{\{x\},\{x,y\}\}:x\in\mathbf{R}^n\text{ and } y\in\mathbf{R}\Big\}.$$
- Another way is to define $\mathbf{R}^n$ as the set of all functions from $I=\{1,\ldots,n\}$ to $\mathbf{R}$: $$\mathbf{R}^n:=\mathbf{R}^I$$

In both cases, the projections $\pi_1,\ldots,\pi_n\colon\mathbf{R}^n\to\mathbf{R}$ are the obvious ones and
\begin{align}
f\colon\mathbf{R}^I&\to\mathbf{R}\times\mathbf{R}\\
\phi&\mapsto\{\{\phi(1)\},\{\phi(1),\phi(2)\}\}
\end{align}
is the natural isomorphism for $n=2$. Suppose $x_1,\ldots,x_n\in\mathbf{R}$, then the element $x\in\mathbf{R}^n$ with $\pi_i(x)=x_i$ for all $i\in I$ is usually denoted by $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$.

---

### Addendum

**Definition of addition and scalar multiplication**:

For all $x,y\in\mathbf{R}^n$ and $\lambda\in\mathbf{R}$, $x+y$ and $\lambda\cdot x$ are the unique elements of $\mathbf{R}^n$ satisfying
$$\pi_i(x+y)=\pi_i(x)+\pi_i(y)$$
and
$$\pi_i(\lambda\cdot x)=\lambda\cdot\pi_i(x)$$
for all $i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$.

So far, we have defined a vector space structure.

**Definition of the inner product**:

The standard inner product is defined as follows:
\begin{align}
\mathbf{R}^n\times\mathbf{R}^n&\to\mathbf{R}\\
(x,y)&\mapsto\sum_{i=1}^n\pi_i(x)\cdot\pi_i(y)
\end{align}
The inner product defines a norm and the norm defines a metric.

Comment: +1 for the answer. It would maybe be instructive to write down the isomorphism between $\prod_{i=1}^n \mathbb R$ and $\mathbb R^n$ explicitly and show that it commutes with projections. The commuting property is important, since $\mathbb R^n$ is in bijection with any other $\mathbb R^m$, but, of course, when $m\neq n$, $\mathbb R^m$ is not $n$-fold Cartesian product.

Comment: @Ennar Thank you! I'm not sure I understand what you mean by the commuting property - let's consider the general case: Are you talking about the fact that given two products $P$ and $P'$ there exists a unique bijection $f\colon P\to P'$ such that $\pi'{}_i\circ f=\pi_i$ for all $i\in I$?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Here the term commuting comes from commutative diagrams in category theory. If all the appropriate compositons of morphisms in a diagram give the same morphisms, we say that the diagram is commutative.

Comment: @Ennar I understand, thank you for the explanation! In this case, I have to draw a triangle (for each $i\in I$), haven't I?

Comment: Yes, that would be the appropriate diagram.

Comment: @Ennar I wanted to add a diagram, but it seems like you can only create crappy diagrams with MathJax. I added a paragraph though.

Comment: Well, the diagram doesn't really matter. What I meant here is that you can define $\varphi\colon \prod_{i=0}^{n-1} \mathbb R\to \mathbb R^n$ and $\psi\colon \mathbb R^n\to \prod_{i=0}^{n-1} \mathbb R$ explicitly: $\varphi(x_0,\ldots,x_{n-1})(i) = x_i$ and $\psi(f) = (f(0),\ldots,f(n-1))$ to show how the two implementations of the product interact.

Comment: @Ennar Added, thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand what you exactly mean by "a deep reason", but here's a very elementary answer that can help understand the connection.

First think of the first definition of $\mathbb R^2$ as $\mathbb R\times \mathbb R$. From the definition of Cartesian product, $\mathbb R\times \mathbb R=\{(a,b):a,b\in \mathbb R\}$ is the collection of **all possible tuples** of real numbers.

Now, consider a function $f:\{0,1\}\to \mathbb R$ and note the tuple $\left(f(0),f(1)\right)$. From the definition of $f$, it is clear that $\left(f(0),f(1)\right)$ is a tuple of real numbers. Now, consider the set of **all such functions**, and name it $S_f$. Keep in mind the range of these functions.

Note that $S_f$ is absolutely same as $\mathbb R\times \mathbb R$ (defined using Cartesian product) by considering a bijection $F:\mathbb R\times \mathbb R \to S_f$ defined by $F((a,b))=f_{ab}$ where $f_{ab}:\{0,1\}\to \mathbb R$ is the function that takes $0$ to $a$ and $1$ to $b$, i.e., $f_{ab}(0)=a$ and $f_{ab}(1)=b$.

Hope that helps.